# Using a Mac keyboard with Windows 7 (UK layout)

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using an Apple wired keyboard with Windows 7. I'd like to get the keyboard layout to match the actual keyboard (which AFAIK resembles a US style keyboard).

I've tried choosing the "United states - international" keyboard layout, which seems to almost match, although the quote button isn't - you need to hit it twice for some reason. None of the other keyb layouts from "US" seem to work either.

Can anyone suggest something to make this keyboard behave properly?

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps: http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/18/apple-uk-keyboard-layout-for-windows/

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by: Control Panel > Clock, Region and language > Region and language > Keyboards and languages > change keyboards and then you can add the appropriate one in there, make sure to remove the other one. hope this helps